# What are the differences between script blocks, subexpressions, and subshells?

Tags: shell, powershell, windows-scripting

On the surface, these constructs seem similar in PowerShell:

`{}` Script Block - from *about_Script_Blocks*:

> In the Windows PowerShell programming language, a script block is a collection of statements or expressions that can be used as a single unit. A script block can accept arguments and return values

`$()` Subexpression Operator - from *about_Operators*:

> Returns the result of one or more statements. For a single result, returns a scalar. For multiple results, returns an array.

In the (contrived) illustration below, the subexpression and invoked script block perform the same functionality, but I'm sure a more complex example can highlight the need to use one or the other. In which scenarios might we choose to use one over the other? How might the choice influence scope and execution peformance?

```
$foo = $(Invoke-Bar; Invoke-Baz)
$foo = &{Invoke-Bar; Invoke-Baz}
```

Do I understand correctly that these expressions execute in the same PowerShell process (unlike many *nix shells that would `fork` a subshell process for similar *command substitution* `$()`)?

Is there a way to—or even a reason to—run a portion of a script in a subshell/subprocess?